# Proguard error while generating signed apk

Tags: android, apk, proguard, signed

I am using latest google play services library project and  I am targeting android 17 (4.2.2) in my app and the min SDK version is android 11 (3.0).I have used mail functionality to send mail using GMail sender, push notifications and also included google play library services jar file and library project to support google maps and also google analytics to track the app screen usability. While signing the apk the proguard displays this error "com.google.android.gms.cast.TextTrackStyle: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager". This is my project properties.txt file

```
-libraryjars \libs\activation.jar
-libraryjars \libs\additionnal.jar
-libraryjars \libs\android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars \libs\gcm.jar
-libraryjars \libs\libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar
-libraryjars \libs\mail.jar
-libraryjars \NiceSupportMapFragment.jar
-libraryjars \nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar
-libraryjars \libs\otr4j.jar

-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose 

-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**

-keep class javax.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
-keep public class Mail {*;}    
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}    
-dontshrink


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: can you review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560244/proguard-error-when-exporting-signed-app-using-android-support-v4-app-honeycomb

Comment: I had reviewed this code and this is not related to my problem