# Android proguard returning error

Tags: android, proguard

```
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zze: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value: can't find referenced class android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Warning: there were 12 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-04-30 14:32:32 - Alkhaliji] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

What's the solution to this error? The same project was working on mac, when i moved to windows..on export am getting this error.

I get the following error with the solution proposed

```
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Note: there were 444 duplicate class definitions.
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [droidux-libproj-2.0.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [actionbarsherlock.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [droidux-pack-wheel-2.5-javadoc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2015-04-30 14:49:39 - Alkhaliji] Error: Can't write [C:\Users\krikor\AppData\Local\Temp\android_3635532493696356272.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\krikor\Desktop\krikor\Alkhaliji\libs\android-support-v4.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich.class]))
```

Comment: the solution there didnt solve my problem

Comment: Add following line -dontwarn android.support.v4.** to your proguard.txt and see it is working or not. See the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/6603889/3831557 on same question

Comment: check my edited comment, and see what error i get if i add those lines posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
# Google Play Services.
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontnote com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult

-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final java.lang.String NULL;
}

-keep,allowobfuscation @interface com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

 # Google Cloud Messaging.
-keep,allowshrinking class **.GCMIntentService
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```